# Connect to Oracle DB with JavaScript without node.js

Tags: javascript, oracle

I need to create a web application that perform queries on a remote Oracle DB Server instance.
Unfortunately it is not possible to install any additional software on the machines - and yes, I know that connecting directly from JavaScript to the Oracle DB Server is dangerous - but I need to do this.

In previous versions of the application the ActiveXComponent in the Internet Explorer was used. But this does not work in any other browser and I can't use Internet Explorer any longer.

So, does anyone has an idea that solves this problem **only with the help of JavaScript**?

Take it easy,
Julian

Comment: To clarify, you want to use client-side JavaScript in a browser to connect to an Oracle database?

Comment: Can you create a web service to run on oracle?  Thats the only think I can think of.

Comment: _and yes, I know that connecting directly from JavaScript to the Oracle DB Server is dangerous_ If you know this then you know it can't be done without something like nodejs. What do you propose will run your javascript?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it on a modern browser, but u might consider installing and configuring  "Oracle REST Data Services" on your db server

Comment: ADyson is right, for the most part. It would be possible to create a light-weight driver that uses, say, HTTPS to communicate with the database. However, such a driver doesn't exist today and may never exist (who knows). As others have mentioned, you will need to create an API (likely a REST API) that you can communicate with. Since you're working with Oracle Database, you might consider ORDS (as Saad mentioned). https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/rest.html There's actually a course on ORDS in PluralSight: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/oracle-rest-data-services

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this from a browser-based JavaScript environment - you don't even get to the point of it being dangerous, it simply won't work to begin with.

You won't be able to load the database drivers, and browser-based JS won't be able to make that kind of socket connection, it can only make HTTP connections (for security reasons, mainly).

The bottom line is, you need some server-side code as an intermediary - either your own creation, or provided by someone else. This is universal for all database platforms. (Even ones you may find which might expose functionality via a HTTP API are like this, it's just that the vendor wrote the API using some server-side code and then deployed it in front of the database - it's still not a *direct* connection to the DBMS).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.
I've found an other solution (java programm connects to the database and shows the webpage in a JWebBrowser). Working for my use-case.